# Como mudar um objeto especifico em um vetor de objetos?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um vetor de objetos que está vindo da minha API que estou salvando no `state`

```js
const state = {
    books: [{name: "Maria", age:"22"},{name:"Roberto", age:20}]
}
```

como mudar a idade de Roberto nesse caso? quais seriam as maneiras para fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dei uma pesquisada no meu caso e consegui achar uma maneira ideal para solucionar, deixei comentários no código pra ajudar na explicação.

```js
const state = {
    books: [{name: "Maria", age:"22"},{name:"Roberto", age:20}]
}

const data = {
    name: "Roberto Silva",
    age: 34
}
// acha o index do objeto especifico
const objIndex = state.books.findIndex(objs => objs.name === "Roberto");
// agora o objeto recebe as alteraçõs recebidas
const updatedObj = { ...this.capitulos[objIndex], ...data };
// nessa etapa irei fazer a reconstrução do objeto
// eu pego todos os objetos do 0 até o index do objeto modificado
// depois coloco o objeto modificado
// e pra finalizar pego todos os objetos a partir do objeto modificado ate o final
const updatedBooks = [
    ...state.books.slice(0, objIndex), 
    updatedObj, 
    ...state.books.slice(objIndex + 1)
];
// agora o books vai receber o novo estado
state.books = updatedBooks;
```

Documentação das funções usadas

- [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [Sintaxe de Espalhamento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 3):

Use o metodo `.find()` da matriz e filtre pela referencia que quizer e mude os valores dentro dos objetos

```js
const state = {
    books: [{name: "Maria", age:"22"},{name:"Roberto", age:20}]
}

state.books.find(x => {
  return x.name === 'Roberto' ? x.age = 0 : null
  })
  
  console.log(state)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: e se eu quiser mudar idade e nome?

Comment: vc teria apenas que fazer as "verificações" em "x" objeto filtrando por suas propriedades

Answer (score 1):

Você primeiro precisa "achar" o roberto na sua 'base', depois pode mudar a idade dele, veja:

```
const state = {
    books: [{name: "Maria", age:"22"},{name:"Roberto", age:20}]
};

robertos = state.books.filter(function (obj){ return obj.name === 'Roberto'});
if (robertos.length>0){
    robertos[0].age = "40"
};
console.log(state);
```

EDIT:

```
buscaNomeEAltera = function (nome, novos_dados){
    buscados = state.books.filter(function (obj){ return obj.name === nome});
    if (buscados.length===1){
        buscados[0] = Object.assign(buscados[0], novos_dados)
    };
};
buscaNomeEAltera('Roberto', {name: 'João', age: 20});
```

Comment: como eu fazeria pra generalizar? por exemplo se eu quisesse mudar vários atributos?

Comment: Você teria que sofisticar mais a solução, criando uma função (por exemplo) que receberia o nome que vc está buscando e o objeto com os novos valores e fazendo um assim dos objetos: `obj2 = Object.assign(robertos[0], {nome: 'James', idade: 28})`